# Assign value to var in Smarty from specific values

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

Can I assign this:

```
{{$phone_numbers.0.phone_number}} 
{{if $phone_numbers.0.extension}} EXT. {{$phone_numbers.0.extension}}{{/if}}
```

to a var in Smarty3? How? I have seen `assign` but I don't know how to concatenate values using it, any help?

**EDIT: is this the right way?**

What do you think about this:

```
{{$phone_number=$phone.phone_number}}
{{if $phone.extension}} {{$phone_number|cat:"EXT. $phone.extension"}}{{/if}}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to put in a variable? The two fragments of code you posted don't produce the same output (even if we assume `$phone` from the second fragment is the same as `$phone_numbers.0` from the first one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative way, in the second example, the right syntax would be:

```
{{$phone_number=$phone_numbers.0.phone_number}}
{{if $phone_numbers.0.extension}}
{{$phone_number=$phone_number|cat:" EXT. "|cat:$phone_numbers.0.extension}}
{{/if}}
```

and then use {{$phone_number}}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use conditionals in [`{assign}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl) but you can use [`{capture}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl):

```
{{capture name=foo assign=bar}}
  {{$phone_numbers.0.phone_number}} 
  {{if $phone_numbers.0.extension}} EXT. {{$phone_numbers.0.extension}}{{/if}}
{{/capture}}
```

This renders the content of the `{capture}` block but doesn't output it. Instead it stores is for later use.

You can find it in [`{$smarty.capture.foo}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.capture) or in the variable `{$bar}`.

The `assign` attribute is optional; you don't use it and the variable `{$bar}` (or whatever name you use) is not modified. However, the captured content is always stored in the variable `{$smarty.capture.foo}` (or whatever name you use for it).